# Matlab - difficulty getting output for my function

Tags: matlab, function, output

I am trying to write a function transform(A) which when given a matrix A returns a new matrix. The new matrix should be obtained according to following: 
if A has more than one row then interchange the first and second row. After this square the elements in the first row.
So far thats what I have written:

```
function[Anew] = transform(A)
dimension = size(A);
if dimension(1) > 1            %if there is more than 1 row
   A([1 2],:)=A([2 1],:);
end
A(1,:,:) = A(1,:,:).^2          %squares elements in the first row
end
```

I tested my function by invoking it in matlab.
I noticed that because i dont have a semi colon next to A(1,:,:) = A(1,:,:).^2
I still obtain the desired result but not as output of the function.
I obtain A =
instead of Anew =

If i put a semi colon next to A(1,:,:) = A(1,:,:).^2; then I dont get an output at all.

Could you tell me what is wrong and what should I change in my program to obtain output as Anew?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a value from a function in Matlab, you must directly assign to it.
In your case, you need to assign to `Anew` at the end of the operation (you could also technically just *use* that variable all-together).

```
function [Output1, Output2] = SomeFunction( ... )
    % Do Some Work

    % Store Output
    Output1 = Result1(:,2) %some output
    Output2 = Result2(3:end, :) %some other result
end

function[Anew] = transform(A)
    dimension = size(A);
    Anew = A;
    if dimension(1) > 1            %if there is more than 1 row
        Anew ([1 2],:)=Anew([2 1],:);
    end
    Anew(1,:,:) = Anew(1,:,:).^2;          %squares elements in the first row
end
```

Comment: I added Anew = A just before the last end. It works yet does not return Anew = .... it returns ans = .... whats wrong? @Rollen D'Souza

Comment: That's how functions work. The variable names are just a sort of placeholder inside the function. When you use the function, you still need to assign it to something (otherwise it is retained in the `ans` variable)

Comment: because I need to interchange row 1 and 2 with command A([1 2],:)=A([2 1],:) As this step consists of assigning values I dont know how I could involve Anew

Comment: I should add, @Hannah, functions cannot change any variable in the global scope. That is, all variable names used inside the function are effectively thrown out. This why you need to return them using the output values, and store them again.

Comment: I am a bit confused would you be able to correct my program and write its solution in order for me to understand what you mean? many thanks @Rollen D'Souza